# Detect RemoteApp in logon script

Tags: remoteapp, remote-desktop-services, logon-scripts

I have a fairly basic vbs logon script which currently detects if a user is on a physical desktop or a remote desktop by checking if the %SESSIONNAME% Environment String is 'Console' or not, and then runs the correct elements. This works wonderfully, however I have just begun to play with RDS RemoteApp and have noticed that running RemoteApp sessions seem to trigger the remote desktop elements of the logon script.

Is there any way within the vbs I can detect that the session is not a 'true' RDP session to avoid running unneccessary elements of the script?

Answer (score 2):

The session is a true RDP session. The difference is that instead of displaying the remote desktop to the user only the application window is displayed. If you click the details button when launching the RemoteApp you'll see the desktop session being created just as you would logging on to a desktop session. Behind the scenes RemoteApps work exactly as a desktop session would: a user profile is created, user variables are set, logon scripts (if any) are run, folder redirection (if configured) is applied, etc., etc.

The underlying technology is still RDS, it's only the presentation that's different.

Comment: I do understand that it is still RDS, however I need to limit the execution of certain elements. As part of the script for example I have a messagebox pop up and a delayed startup of an application (I know probably bad practice). When a RemoteApp session launches the logon script both of these elements are shown within the RemoteApp session window, which is obviously impedes the seamlessness of the window.

Comment: +1 - A comparison of the environment between a non-RemoteApp and a RemoteApp TS session on a W2K8R2 machine reveals no difference. Your logon script isn't going to have much more that the environment to use as the basis for comparison so I think you're probably in trouble. You might want to consider assigning the logon script using group policy and using loopback policy processing to assign a version of the script that doesn't have the interactive UI elements.